# NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I wrote an SQL query to create a view for the database I'm working on and the query works as expected:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.current_model
AS SELECT pm.model_id,
    mp.name,
    ga.pit,
    pm.description,
    pm.created_datetime,
    pm.folder_full_path,
    pm.status
   FROM prediction_model pm
     JOIN material_property mp ON pm.property_id = mp.auto_id
     JOIN geographic_applicability ga ON ga.model_id = pm.auto_id
  WHERE pm.status::text <> 'INACTIVE'::text AND (pm.created_datetime IN ( SELECT max(pm2.created_datetime) AS max
           FROM prediction_model pm2
             JOIN geographic_applicability ga2 ON ga2.model_id = pm2.auto_id
             JOIN material_property mp2 ON pm2.property_id = mp2.auto_id
          GROUP BY mp2.name, ga2.pit));
```

Now I need to add this view to the sqlalchemy schema for the database. I have successfully implemented couple other views, but this one gets me lost (mind you, I have almost no previous sqlalchemy experience). This is what I have come up with so far:

```py
    @classmethod
    def current_model_view(cls):
        j1 = cls.prediction_model.join(cls.material_property,
                                       cls.prediction_model.c.property_id == cls.material_property.c.auto_id)
        j2 = j1.join(cls.geographic_applicability,
                     cls.prediction_model.c.auto_id == cls.geographic_applicability.c.model_id)

        s1 = cls.prediction_model.join(cls.geographic_applicability,
                                       cls.geographic_applicability.c.model_id == cls.prediction_model.c.auto_id)
        s2 = s1.join(cls.material_property, cls.prediction_model.c.property_id == cls.material_property.c.auto_id)

        max_date = select(max(cls.prediction_model.c.created_datetime)).\
            select_from(s2).group_by(cls.material_property.c.name, cls.geographic_applicability.c.pit)

        view_selectable = select([cls.material_property.c.name,
                                  cls.geographic_applicability.c.pit,
                                  cls.prediction_model.c.description,
                                  cls.prediction_model.c.created_datetime,
                                  cls.prediction_model.c.folder_full_path,
                                  cls.prediction_model.c.status]).\
            select_from(j2).\
            where(and_(not_(cls.prediction_model.c.status == 'INACTIVE'),
                       cls.prediction_model.c.created_datetime.in_(max_date)))
        return view_selectable
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python/mhi_versionist/mhi_versionist/data_base/tracker_database_schema.py", line 320, in <module>
    create_view('current_model', ModelDB.current_model_view(), ModelDB.model_db_meta)
  File "C:/python/mhi_versionist/mhi_versionist/data_base/tracker_database_schema.py", line 154, in current_model_view
    max_date = select(max(cls.prediction_model.c.created_datetime)).\
  File "C:\python\mhi_versionist\venv2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\operators.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "C:\python\mhi_versionist\venv2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 762, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\mhi_versionist\venv2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\operators.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "C:\python\mhi_versionist\venv2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\type_api.py", line 67, in operate
    return o[0](self.expr, op, *(other + o[1:]), **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\mhi_versionist\venv2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\default_comparator.py", line 237, in _getitem_impl
    _unsupported_impl(expr, op, other, **kw)
  File "C:\python\mhi_versionist\venv2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\default_comparator.py", line 241, in _unsupported_impl
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

Not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in the following line:

`max_date = select(max(cls.prediction_model.c.created_datetime)).\`

you're using Python's `max` function, rather than passing the sql `max` function. Can you try using `max` from `sqlalchemy` instead? It sits in the `func` module. So write:

`max_date = select([func.max(cls.prediction_model.c.created_datetime)]).\`

Note that you also need to use a list in your `select` query, hence the added `[ ]`.

On another note, if the `ForeignKey` relationships have been defined correctly in your table definitions, you don't need to tell `sqlalchemy` explicitely how to do the join. So in that case you could get away with something like:

```
    j1 = cls.prediction_model.join(cls.material_property).join(cls.geographic_applicability)
    s1 = cls.prediction_model.join(cls.geographic_applicability).join(cls.material_property)
```